# How to redirect in a base controller's OnActionExecuting method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect

On OnActionExecuting for a controller, I'm trying to do a permanent redirect.  The code looks like this:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
  var resolvedUrl = "http://www.cnn.com";
  filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(resolvedUrl);
  filterContext.Result.ExecuteResult(filterContext);
  return;
}
```

It's not immediately redirecting because this method is in a base class, and after the return statement, the inherited class's `OnActionExecuting` method is called.

Question: how do I do the redirect and stop there, and not do anything in the inherited class. Thanks.

Note: in the child class (one that's inheriting from base), I have `base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);` in its `OnActionExecuting`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't call ExecuteResult() from within an action filter.  Setting filterContext.Result to a non-null value is sufficient to prevent the MVC pipeline from invoking further filters.

The subclassed type should instead be changed to read:

```
base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
if (filterContext.Result != null) {
  return; // something got short-circuited
}
```